# Adding buttons on grid

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid with 3 column, and one of those column has an `actioncolumn`, with a button on it;

My scenario; If the user comes from clicking on a button of the `friend view` then i need to show the following grid (with the actioncolumn button), but when the user comes from clicking on the `teacher view`, then i need to have 2 buttons displayed in the action column. How can i do that ?

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Action Column Demo',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('friendStore'),
    columns: [
        {text: 'First Name',  dataIndex:'firstname'},
        {text: 'Last Name',  dataIndex:'lastname'},
        {
            xtype:'actioncolumn',
            width:50,
            items: [{
                icon: 'extjs/examples/shared/icons/fam/cog_edit.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
                tooltip: 'Edit',
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    alert("Edit " + rec.get('firstname'));
                }
            }]
        }
    ],
    width: 250,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create two actioncolumns, one with one button and the other with two buttons, and hide the one that you don't need.

```
...
xtype : 'actioncolumn',
hide  : this.fromTeacherView, //a boolean
...
```

the `fromTeacherView` is in this case a boolean that is a config parameter given to the grid when it is instantiated.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: where should i add the above code ? I think i should add a IF-ELSE statement to see if its teacherview or friend view. how could i add this functionality ?

Comment: i don't really know what teacherview or friendview are... so is kind of difficult to say. But what I do when i have this sort of problem is, I pass the grid a boolean (or not) stating what type of grid it is, something that the grid is expecting since i configured it like that